# How to make an Autorun CD/DVD?

Tags: dvd, compact-disc, autorun

How do I burn `.exe` files to a CD/DVD so that it will give options which one I want to install when the CD is inserted into the CD-ROM and run the applications on the disc automatically?

Comment: Did you even bother to google it?

Answer (score 3):

You're looking for `Autorun.inf` entries, you simply create a new file on the root of the CD/DVD/USB and call it "Autorun.inf".  You can edit it with any text editor and update it with the parameters you need (see the linked items from MSDN).

> From MSDN: [Creating an AutoRun-enabled CD-ROM Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144202(v=vs.85).aspx)
>   AutoRun is a feature of the Windows operating system. It automates the procedures for installing and configuring products designed for Windows-based platforms that are distributed on CD-ROMs. When users insert an AutoRun-enabled compact disc into their CD-ROM drive, AutoRun automatically runs an application on the CD-ROM that installs, configures, or runs the selected product.

You'll probably mostly just need the [Autorun.info Entries](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc144200(v=vs.85).aspx) link at the bottom of that page.

Example `Autorun.inf` file:

```
[autorun]
label=Welcome To My EXE
open=myexe.exe /silent
icon=MyExeIcon.ico
```

**Note**: If you have file extensions hidden by default in Windows explorer, it will probably save your file as `Autorun.inf.txt`, so if it doesn't work - that may be why.  To toggle that:

1. Open Windows Explorer (just navigate to a folder)
2. Hit <kbd>ALT</kbd> on your keyboard
3. In the menu that appears up top, select `Tools > Folder Options`
4. Select the `View` tab
5. In the `Advanced Settings` scrollbox, toggle the checkbox for `Hide extensions for known file types`.
6. Double check the naming of your `Autorun.*` file to make sure it saved correctly.
7. Once you're done, feel free to re-hide extensions if you prefer that view for normal use.

Comment: Remember that Windows disables autorun by default from 2 years

Comment: And for good reason. No sane installation has this on. Not even with a good and up to date virus scanner.