# How to Make an Autorun CD /DVD with multiple .exe files?

Tags: windows, dvd, compact-disc, autorun

I have asked a question about :[How to make an Autorun CD/DVD?](https://superuser.com/questions/681303/how-to-make-an-autorun-cd-dvd)
@nerdwaller gave me an answer.
Now I want to know  whether is it possible to make an autorun CD/DVD which will contain the following :

Easy GIF Animator v5.6 Setup.exe,  KMPlayer_3.6.0.exe, MS office2010.iso, and a folder named : 'Easy GIF Animator v5.6 Pro + Patch' containing files 'Easy GIF Animator v5.6 Pro Patch.exe, Easy GIF Animator v5.6 Setup.exe, Instructions.txt, RCS.png'. 
I use Nero burning ROM 12. Is it possible to do with nero or any other easy way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. this can't be done with the `autorun.inf` alone.

---

You could create a batchfile `open.bat` and instruct `autorun.inf` to run that:

file `autorun.inf`

```
[autorun]
open=open.bat
```

file `open.bat`

```
my_first.exe
my_second.exe
```

But you'll notice the `.exe` will run simultaneous. If that's not desired you could use the following:

file `open.bat`

```
start /b/wait my_first.exe
start /b/wait my_second.exe
```

You will have the black window open of the batch-file during the installation.

---

Another option is to use a separate program to execute your `.exe`s.

One such option is [AutoRun](http://www.autorun.co.uk/documentation.htm). (not free)

[Here](https://forums.hak5.org/index.php?/topic/4653-how-to-autorun-multiple-files-using-autoruninf) is another ([AutoRunPro.exe](http://www.autorunpro.com/) also not free)

And [another one](http://rjlsoftware.com/support/faq/sa.cfm?q=170&n=4) (AutoRun Wizard, again not free).

I'm beginning to think there are no free option (besides making a batch-file yourself).

---

There is another possibility (and **more professional looking**). That's to use [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) to write your own setup-file. In that setup-file you can execute the other `.exe`s.

Comment: thank you @
Rik. I have done the job with your given answer.